# I have an unserialized data. Now how can i cut the first part of array and transform it in json format?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-8

I have an unserialized array. Now i want to cut the first part of it the _PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name:"Payslip_Label". For example, below is the array that i want to cut

```
    [{"__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name":"Payslip_Label","label":"Position","value":"HR 
     Assistant","variable":"position"},

    {"__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name":"Payslip_Label","label":"Monthly 
   Rate","value":"10000","variable":"monthly_rate"}]
```

I want output like this

```
    [{"label":"Position","value":"HR 
      Assistant","variable":"position"},

     {"label":"Monthly 
      Rate","value":"10000","variable":"monthly_rate"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

simple, just `unset` the unwanted keys

```
<?php

$json ='[{"__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name":"Payslip_Label","label":"Position","value":"HR Assistant","variable":"position"},{"__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name":"Payslip_Label","label":"Monthly Rate","value":"10000","variable":"monthly_rate"}]';
   
$data = json_decode($json,true);

foreach($data as $d => $i)
{
   unset($data[$d]['__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name']);
}
    
$json = json_encode($data);
print_r($json);
```